# Incurring too much cost for Elastic Load Balancer while EC2 is off. What are my options?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I just figured out that while my EC2 instance are stopped, ELB are still up and incurring costs. Here are a few of my questions.

1. If I have 2 EC2 running for a month then does that mean ELB's free tier 750 hrs is spent by 2 instances of EC2? Hence I will only end up w/ two free months of ELB?
2. Is there a way for ELB to be turned off like an instance of EC2? So that I can save up my 750s of free tier time when I'm not in the process of developing?
3. I have a custom domain. Is it possible to link it to my EC2 without using ELB?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have 2 EC2 running for a month then does that mean ELB's free
>   tier 750 hrs is spent by 2 instances of EC2? Hence I will only end up
>   w/ two free months of ELB?

No in free tier you have 750 Hrs for EC2 and 750 Hrs and 15 GB data processing for ELB. Both are separate 750 Hrs EC2 usage will not use up ELB 750 Hrs usage.

> Is there a way for ELB to be turned off like an instance of EC2? So
>   that I can save up my 750s of free tier time when I'm not in the
>   process of developing?

No you cannot turn off a ELB you can delete that ELB but remember your ELB end point changes when you launch new ELB.

> I have a custom domain. Is it possible to link it to my EC2 without
>   using ELB?

Yes you can do that, just make sure your EC2 has a Elastic IP address (Elastic IP is free when in use with a EC2 if you are not using it you will get charged so release the Elastic IP when not in use, again you will not get the same elastic IP when you want one). Once you associate the Elastic IP to the instance you add a A-Record for your custom domain to point to the Elastic IP and your website will work.

Comment: Elastic IP addresses are charged for if the EIP is not associated with a running EC2 instance. So while your EC2 instance is stopped, you'll be charged for the Elastic IP.